# Help in proving this inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

$a,b,c \in R^+: abc=1$

Prove that $1+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\ge\frac{6}{ab+bc+ca}$

I tried replacing the RHS using GM-HM

To P.T

$LHS\ge 2GM(ab,bc,ca)=2$

But this means that $3 \ge a+b+c$

which is clealy false by AM-GM

How to proceed I don't know.

I tried assigning $a,b,c$ as the roots of a cubic but this also didn't work

Comment: \ge will give you $\ge$.

Comment: Thanks it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM $$1+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{3}{a+b+c}}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$2\sqrt{\frac{3}{a+b+c}}\geq\frac{6}{ab+ac+bc}$$ or
$$(ab+ac+bc)^2\geq3(a+b+c)abc$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Can you please describe how you got the motivation to go to the last line from the previous line?

Comment: @Yes it's me Because any symmetric polynomial we can write as sum of squares. I tried to make it and it turned out.

Comment: @Yesit'sme It's also known as [Newton's Inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities). Alternatively, with $ x = ab, y = bc , z = ca$, we know that $ ( x+y+z)^2 \geq 3 (xy + yz + xx ) \Rightarrow (ab+bc+ca)^2 \geq  3 (a+b+c)(abc)$.